# How to change class of all children with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I have the following syntax in which I want to remove all css classes from the link tags. How can I do this using jquery?

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="" class="foo">aa</a></li>
<li><a href="" class="bar">aa</a></li>
<li><a href="" class="yay">aa</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) method; if you call it without an argument it removes all classes:

```
$('#nav ul a').removeClass();
```

> Description: Remove a single class, multiple classes, or all classes from each element in the set of matched elements.

Obviously you can chain `.addClass('someClass')` in the same call; you asked to *change* the class in your question's subject after all. ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#nav ul li a').each(function(){
    this.className = '';
});
```

Finds all anchors, based on `div#nav` selector, and removes all class names.

Comment: Works, but no need to iterate over the elements in your code - you can use `.removeClass()`

Comment: +1 What's wrong with explicitly looping? If in the loop `.removeClass()` was used, that would be a different story, but that's not the case here.

Comment: ...hmmm, seems that there is a performance impact though. Probably because of the function call that is avoided.

Comment: ...but to down-vote this answer is just dumb. The performance difference will never be noticeable. If performance is that much of a concern, jQuery wouldn't be used in the first place.

Comment: @epascarello: If I was using `removeClass` you would be correct. I'm just short-circuiting; @amnotiam: Performance is negligible. I'me repalcing a call to [`removeClass`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L76-107) with an embedded loop and just bringing the loop out-front and calling a direct DOM property myself. Any loss in using `each` is gained in fewer entries in the call stack. (or so as I see it).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove every class then it's this:

```
$('#nav a').each(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('class');
});
```

Comment: Using attributes when modifying existing elements is almost always a bad idea. Use `this.className = '';` or `$(this).prop('className', '')` (but see my comment in BradChristie's answer)

Comment: @epascarello Open to correction but I think it uses each internally regardless.

Comment: I meant, there was no need to do the each, it could have been done like the selected answer which would do the loop internally. Your solution would be great if there were changing multiple things on the element, not just one attribute.

Comment: I'm going to leave it as it is and chalk it down as a stylistic choice :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$("a").removeClass();`

here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/UPsEK/